# Code is not Exit always in the wait mode

Tags: powershell

Before I was using a piece of code like this  `$prog="cmd.exe";
    $params=@('/C','"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"','connector.log')
$rc=start-process $prog $params -WorkingDirectory "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus" -RedirectStandardOutput $emailconnecter_log -PassThru -wait` The issue was with this code is not returing error code. Later I usedd a code like here below

```
$errorlog = "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\logs\error.log"
$emailconnecter_log = "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\logs\connector.log"


$prog="cmd.exe"
$params=@('/C','"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"','connector.log')

$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = $prog
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $emailconnecter_log
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = $params
$pinfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus"
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host "stdout: $stdout"
Write-Host "stderr: $stderr"
Write-Host "exit code: " + $p.ExitCode
    if ($p.ExitCode -gt 0) 
    {Some code is here }
```

Now the issue is  `$p.WaitForExit()` not exiting, i was debuggin through PowershellISE. I dont know Why the code is not exiting. Also I want to write the console output to `$emailconnecter_log`. Previously everything working except the return code. Pleae help me.

Comment: If you run the batch file outside of PowerShell does it work? i don't know if you have addressed this in another question but we still don't know how that batch works so the Community has to guess....

Comment: The batch works Perfectly. I stuck here to check the return code. If I use Start-process Cmdlet it works perfectly, the extra thing i need to do is check the status of the process